# Inflating a view and setting the onclicklistener causing nullpointer

Tags: java, android

Following code causing issues.

```
item = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.submenu_layout);

        child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_mainscreen_submenu_seismometer, item);

        //Load the views. Do this every time, avoid null reference.
        mAusisImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ausis_image);
        mAusisText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ausis_text);

        mAusisImage.setOnClickListener(this); // << Issue here. Null.
        mAusisText.setOnClickListener(this);
```

When inflating this view it causes a nullpointerexception on the highlighted line.

I've tried using the item to findViewByID but it doesn't work.

---

I forgot to add the view to the ViewGroup, silly me. Following code fixed it:

```
//Before the onClickListner
item.addView(child);
```

Comment: Which `layout` contains `mAusisimage`?`layout_mainscreen_submenu_seismometer`?

Comment: obviously mAusisImage is null.

Comment: Add more code, or we're of no use.

Comment: Add it as an answer and accept. It may help others.

Answer (score 0):

from the top of my Head try this:

```
mAusisImage = (ImageView) child.findViewById(R.id.ausis_image);
```

guessing that second setOnClickListener will throw NPE as well, just do the same with that view

guessing that the ImageView is within `R.layout.layout_mainscreen_submenu_seismometer`, but due to the short code snippet i cant be sure :)